# How to start developing OpenDDS on Qt5.8 in linux?

Tags: centos, qt5, opendds

After a long process, we chose CentOS 7.3 + Qt5.8 + OpenDDS 3.10 to use for our needs.

Now I am looking into how exactly to make OpenDDS usable in Qt5?

There is literately no result here when searching "opendds qt".

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the OpenDDS distribution, under [examples/DCPS/ishapes](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/tree/master/examples/DCPS/ishapes) there is an example that uses Qt4, shouldn't be to hard to migrate that to Qt5.